# Vue.js: Setting v-model and v-bind:value on same input element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a `Vue` component that contains a form that will send an email.

I am having an issue with displaying a default value in the input field. When the page loads I want the email input field to display the user's default email address and only change the value if the user over-writes it with a new email.

I know you can't have `v-bind` and `v-model` on the same `<input>` so how would I go about accomplishing this task?

```
<input
  v-model="emailAddress"
  :value="emailAddress"
  type="email"
  name="email"
  id="email-field"
/>
```

```
export default {
  props: { defaultEmail: String },
  data() {
    return {
      emailAddress: this.defaultEmail || ''
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `v-model` to bind the input value:

```js
const emailComponent = Vue.component('emailComponent', { 
  template: '#emailComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      emailAddress: this.defaultEmail || ''
    }
  },
  props: { defaultEmail: String },
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { emailComponent }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <email-component default-email="my email"/>
</div>

<template id="emailComponent">
  <input
    v-model="emailAddress"
    type="email"
    name="email"
    id="email-field"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` does the same thing as

```
<input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value"
>
```

So you do not need value binding, you can remove it just leave `v-model`.
Check vue doc for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components